# Partial assertion issue on Sahi, Javascript

Tags: javascript, automation, sahi

```
_assertEqual("/" + "887.90" + "/", 887)
```

The above code is not working. We are using Sahi pro automation tool, a JavaScript-based tool.

Kindly suggest how to handle the assertion.

Answer (score 2):

The API _assertEqual works like this:

```
_assertEqual($expected, $actual[, $message])
```

Now I am not sure if you are using correct values for expected and actual or not, but try this:

```
_assertEqual("/887.90/", "887");
```

Just note that this will give you false. This is because you are saying that 887 should match a pattern like 887.90, which comes out as false. I think what you may be looking for is:

```
_assertEqual("887.90", "/887/");
```